# dataframe line plot is not plotting a line with column values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I think there is something wrong with the data in my dataframe, but I am having a hard time coming to a conclusion. I think there might be some missing datetime values, which is the index of the dataframe. Given that there are over 1000 rows, it isn't possible for me to check each row manually. Here is a picture of my data and the corresponding line plt. Clearly this isn't a line plot!

Is there any way to supplement the possible missing values in my dataframe somehow?
[image]

I also did a line plot in seaborne as well to get another perspective, but I don't think it was immediately helpful.

[image]

Comment: Your index goes three times between the about 420 days between 2020-01-01 and 2021-03-16. Note that you didn't create a seaborn plot.  For seaborn you need something like `sns.lineplot(data=young_df.reset_index(), x='index', y='cum_count', hue='age_group')`

Comment: Please don't post code and data as image, always post them as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have effectively done same as I have simulated.  Really you have a multi-index **date** and **age_group**. plotting both together means line jumps between the two.  Separate them out and plot as separate lines and it is as you expect.

```
d = pd.date_range("1-jan-2020", "16-mar-2021")
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({"daily_percent":np.sort(np.random.uniform(0.5,1, len(d)))}, index=d).assign(age_group="0-9 Years"),
                pd.DataFrame({"daily_percent":np.sort(np.random.uniform(0,0.5, len(d)))}, index=d).assign(age_group="20-29 Years")])
                

df.plot(kind="line", y="daily_percent", color="red")
df.set_index("age_group", append=True).unstack(1).droplevel(0, axis=1).plot(kind="line", color=["red","blue"])
```

[image]